# How to resolve 403 on spring security JWT authentication for public resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a JWT based authentication using spring security in a spring boot API, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. On my implementation of [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://github.com/wallysoncarvalho/jwt-auth-spring-security/blob/main/src/main/java/wally/info/auth/WebSecurityConfig.java) I permit access to `auth/**` resource, but when I make a request to, for example, `/auth/login`, I get a 403. It seems that it is ignoring the "public" resources.

The `csrf()` is disabled.

This is the repository: https://github.com/wallysoncarvalho/jwt-auth-spring-security

I enabled DEBUG mode and that's what I get:

```
Request received for POST '/auth/login?username=wally&password=wally':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@585d8cc6

servletPath:/auth/login
pathInfo:null
headers: 
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
accept: */*
postman-token: 91c2a071-a353-4d77-9c7c-b04a43b94081
host: localhost:8091
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 0


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JwtFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2020-12-22 20:21:15.919 DEBUG 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /auth/login?username=wally&password=wally
2020-12-22 20:21:15.937 DEBUG 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2020-12-22 20:21:15.948 DEBUG 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2020-12-22 20:21:15.960  INFO 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for POST '/error?username=wally&password=wally':

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@6d88bc8c

servletPath:/error
pathInfo:null
headers: 
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
accept: */*
postman-token: 91c2a071-a353-4d77-9c7c-b04a43b94081
host: localhost:8091
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 0


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JwtFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2020-12-22 20:21:15.961 DEBUG 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error?username=wally&password=wally
2020-12-22 20:21:15.961 DEBUG 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2020-12-22 20:21:15.967 DEBUG 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2020-12-22 20:21:15.998 DEBUG 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /error?username=wally&password=wally] with attributes [authenticated]
2020-12-22 20:21:16.022 DEBUG 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2020-12-22 20:21:16.025 DEBUG 6288 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**",);
}
```

And your @Configuration class must implements `WebMvcConfigurer`

**Edit**
Also enable WebSecurity in your config class by annotating it with `@EnableWebSecurity`

Comment: But does it need to implement any of its methods? Until now these changes doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Have you enabled WebSecurity with the annotation `@EnableWebSecurity` ?

Comment: dm_tr, actually just adding the method that you provided made it work. I was already using the annotation and did not need to implement the interface. I'm just trying to understand why it is only working with this method. Thanks!

Comment: The web.ignoring tells your security context to not control urls in the antMatchers. If this answer your question mark it as the correct one to help future readers. Happy coding